# Is creating commercial study guide materials for a trademarked exam considered fair use / illegal?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use

Provided that no text or diagrams are directly used, is creating commercial study materials considered against fair use / illegal? Given the amount of study guides available for various trademarked exams, it seems that this is considered fair use so long as there is not any material directly used.

Comment: Are you sure you wonder about violating the *trademark* of the exam? It seems to me like violating the *copyright* would be the bigger concern. Although trademark law might also be a problem. When a company trademarked SuperHardExam®, then advertising a product named "SuperHardExam Study Guide" *might* give them grounds to sue for trademark violation.

Comment: Good question. Suppose that "SuperHardExam Study Guide" did not actually use any text or figures from any material provided from the vendor of SuperHardExam . In other words, SuperHardExam was not for a specific product (for example, a software product, a specific make/model of a physical product, etc) but perhaps a professional designation (Accounting, Project Management, etc). Does any reference to SuperHardExam violate fair use in this case?